# Array[0] giving different results

Tags: c++

Why in the following:

```
int hashTable[0b11111111111111111111];
int hash = 0;
hashTable[hash]++;
if (hashTable[hash] == 1)
   // do stuff
```

is the condition not necessarily triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array

```
        int hashTable[0b11111111111111111111];
```

is not initialized and have indeterminate value. You have to initialize it like this to have it correctly work:

```
        int hashTable[0b11111111111111111111] = {};
```

Since the array is very big, using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is better.

```
        std::vector<int> hashTable(0b11111111111111111111);
```

Comment: yes I found out while testing! any idea about the stack buffer overflow?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Thanks, any reason why vector would work better than array for huge arrays?

Comment: Because data for vector are allocated on the heap while simple local arrays not marked as `static` are (typically) allocated on the stack.